# Submersible electronics

Tags: sensor, waterproof, underwater

I'm currently working on a hobby project that uses a [MS5540C](https://www.te.com/commerce/DocumentDelivery/DDEController?Action=showdoc&DocId=Data+Sheet%7FMS5540C%7FB3%7Fpdf%7FEnglish%7FENG_DS_MS5540C_B3.pdf%7FCAT-BLPS0033).
It will basically measure the water depth and temperature.

My general thinking was to encapsulate the whole thing (except the sensor) in wax to make it water proof.

Could I use epoxy instead? What general consensus?

**added:**
The sensor will be dropped to at least 10m - 20m. I'm still playing with the idea of having the sensor...or the whole device (sensor ESP32 and battery) submerged.

Comment: Epoxy resists it but not leak proof

Comment: Generally you'd use a waterproof housing and then also perhaps encapsulat e the PBA or use a conformal coating. Waterproof housings usually use a O-ring to ensure a proper seal. Conformal coatings must form a void free layer against the surface and have low water solubility.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon Suggestions noted...Thank you...Also adding a little more info. Put it in an answer and I will mark it.

Comment: So..It there a particular conformal coating that seems to be better that others? Acrylic, polyU..etc..etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> will basically measure the water depth and temperature.
>   My general thinking was to encapsulate the whole thing (except the sensor) in wax to make it water proof.
>   Could I use epoxy instead? What general consensus?

Generally you'd use a waterproof housing and then also perhaps encapsulat e the PBA or use a conformal coating. Waterproof housings usually use a O-ring to ensure a proper seal. Conformal coatings must form a void free layer against the surface and have low water solubility. –

> Is there a particular conformal coating that seems to be better that others? Acrylic, polyU...

Dow Corning Dowsil [CC-2570](https://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C1CHBF_enNZ834NZ839&sxsrf=ACYBGNRdfSsVldJNTzXE4wlBA8PYJ0wu5Q%3A1569729056695&ei=ICqQXcmMKoHyrAHt0ILIBw&q=%22cc-2570%22+conformal+coating&oq=%22cc-2570%22+conformal+coating&gs_l=psy-ab.3...11000.17131..17584...0.0..0.237.1235.0j6j1......0....1..gws-wiz.......35i39.RPj5HYqUMKA&ved=0ahUKEwjJnMW2kPXkAhUBOSsKHW2oAHkQ4dUDCAs&uact=5) is "very good indeed".  It costs an arm and 3 legs in small volumes and much less in not much larger volumes. [Here](https://www.ellsworth.com/products/conformal-coatings/silicone/dow-cc-2570-rtv-silicone-conformal-coating-clear-3.6-kg-pail/) about $US100/kg in 3.6 kg pails, and [Here](https://www.ellsworth.com/products/conformal-coatings/silicone/dow-1-2577-rtv-silicone-conformal-coating-clear-453-g-bottle/) $128 for a 453 g bottle. 
It can be sprayed, dipped or brushed on and only needs a 0.1mm coat to work well enough. So a little goes a long long way.
(V = A x t. So 1 litre = 10 m^2 x 0.1 mm)

It will "go off" if not stored well BUT if stored in a wll sealed bottle inside multiple sealed plastic bags will still be usable 10 years on (ask me how I know).

Comment: OK...How do you know?

Comment: @ChrisCatignani :-) | In about 2008-2010 I considered 2570 for use in products being manufactures in China. A Canadian I was working with had in earlier times used it "by the drum load". To get some practical experience of it I bought a bottle of it (in NZ). I did not use a vast amount of it at the time (a little goes a long way) and as it wasn't cheap I decided to attempt to prolong its life. I took special care to reseal it well and to seal it in multiple plastic bags each with excess air squashed out and rubber band sealed. Since then I've used it occasionally with success.

Comment: Thanks for the reply...I make custom fishing rods and have a product by U40 that's the same way. They have a container that's supposed to keep it dry by Im not 100% how it works...its a can and a screw!! http://www.u-40.com/products.aspx?itemid=3298&prodid=16532&pagetitle=Perma-Gloss-Container-(4oz)

Comment: @ChrisCatignani Last attempt to use it in 2020  failed - it had gone from runny to excessively gloopy. Desiccant may have been a good idea :-)  :-(.

Comment: Thanks for the update Russell

Answer (score 1):

Put your electronics inside of the rubber envelope filled with oil.  The rubber and oil will keep the water away while transmitting the pressure and temperature to the sensors.

The oil could be silicone oil, or mineral oil, as long as it's compatible with the rubber.
The rubber could be a finger cut off from a glove.

> The sensor will be dropped to at least 10m - 20m.

Note that the max pressure with the MS5540C can measure is 1.1 bar.  That's only about 11 meters of water.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out...I mistook (ISO 22810) of withstanding 100m of water pressure as working to 100m. I see now the range is 10 - 1100 mbar. I may need another sensor.